# WC on OSX - Return includes spaces

Tags: macos, bash, wc

When I run the word count command in OSX terminal like `wc -c file.txt` I get the below answer that includes spaces padded before the answer.  Does anyone know why this happens, or how I can prevent it?

```
    18000 file.txt
```

I would expect to get:

```
18000 file.txt
```

This occurs using bash or bourne shell.

Comment: I am getting no spaces...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose it is a way of getting outputs to line up nicely, and as far as I know there is no option to wc which fine tunes the output format.

You could get rid of them pretty easily by piping through `sed 's/^ *//'`, for example.

There may be an even simpler solution, depending on why you want to get rid of them.

Answer (score 6):

The POSIX standard for [`wc`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/wc.html) may be read to *imply* that there are no leading blanks, but does not say that *explicitly*.   Standards are like that.

This is what it *says*:

> By default, the standard output shall contain an entry for each input file of the form:

```
"%d %d %d %s\n", <newlines>, <words>, <bytes>, <file>
```

and does not mention the formats for the single-column options such as `-c`.

A quick check shows me that AIX, OSX, Solaris use a format which specifies the number of digits for the value — to align columns (and differ in the number of digits). HPUX and Linux do not.

So it is just an implementation detail.

Answer (score 1):

At least under macOS/bash `wc` exhibits the behavior of outputting trailing positional TABs.

It can be avoided using expr:

```
echo -n "some words" | expr $(wc -c) 
>> 10
```

```
echo -n "some words" | expr $(wc -w) 
>> 2
```

**Note:** The `-n` prevents echoing a newline character which would count as 1 in `wc -c`

Comment: This is working in macOS Catalina terminal(not zsh) but not in bash

Comment: @tom10271, ...a terminal, on its own, doesn't run any code; there has to be a shell running in that terminal, whether it's ash, bash, zsh, ksh, ...

Answer (score 0):

This bugs me every time I write a script that counts lines or characters.  I wish that `wc` were defined not to emit the extra spaces, but it's not, so we're stuck with them.

When I write a script, instead of

```
nlines=`wc -l $file`
```

I always say

```
nlines=`wc -l < $file`
```

so that `wc`'s output doesn't include the filename, but that doesn't help with the extra spaces.  The trick I use next is to add 0 to the number, like this:

```
nlines=`expr $nlines + 0`      # get rid of trailing spaces
```

Answer (score -1):

This works for me:

```
var=$(cat test.txt|wc -l|sed 's/      //g')
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explaination about the `sed ` and make sure having taken in account the question author context in your answer (Mac OS & POSIX shell, etc)