# Unexpected leading spaces while using wc -l command

Tags: perl, unix, wc

I am trying to execute the below command - but the output has some leading space introduced.

```
ls -lrt | wc -l
     29
echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
```

When I run the same command on a different machine,the output is as expected.

```
ls -lrt | wc -l
183
echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
```

The leading spaces is causing my perl validation to fail

```
unless ( $phCountRet->{COUNT} =~ /^\d+$/ ){
...
}
```

I can opt to trim the leading white spaces and then do the validation,but it wont be a clean solution.

Any pointer as to what might be causing this will be a great help.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10238363/how-to-get-wc-l-to-print-just-the-number-of-lines-without-file-name Does one of these machines run AIX?

Comment: Why do you think trimming the whitespace is not clean?  `ls | wc -l | sed -e 's/^ *//'` doesn't seem any less clean than `ls -lrt | wc -l`, but you could just do the equivalent of `perl -E 'say length glob "*"'` and not shell out to wc at all.

Comment: When you run `wc` with multiple file names, it aligns and right-justifies the numbers so they're more legible (at least some implementations do). The output is meant for to be human-readable than machine-readable. You just have to allow for variations in whitespace in the output.

Answer (score 2):

use

```
unless ( $phCountRet->{COUNT} =~ /^\s*\d+$/ ){
```

this matches also numbers with blanks in front.

Comment: Thanks Jens. Yes, I can definitely modify the regex to suit this case.But,I would still be more interested to know why the leading spaces are introduced.

Comment: @Soumya Think for better readability. But also think that this question will be off-topic.

Comment: This answer simply repeats back to OP to follow the suggestion which OP made, and does not address the question which OP made.

Answer (score 2):

As I noted in *[WC on OSX - Return includes spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30927590/wc-on-osx-return-includes-spaces/30927885#30927885)*, this is an implementation detail, which is not explicit in the POSIX standard (so it depends on the implementer's preference to *align* columns—or not).