# Why is [ "$(ls *.jpg | wc -l)" = 0 ] always false unless the quotes are removed?

Tags: bash, shell

Given that there are no `jpg` files in my current working directory, why do the two scripts `jpg1.sh` and `jpg2.sh` give different results? How to understand the difference? Note that the only difference between the scripts is whether to have double quotes around the `$()` command substitution.

```sh
$ cat jpg1.sh
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$(ls *.jpg | wc -l)" = 0 ]; then
    echo "yes"
else
    echo "no"
fi

$ ./jpg1.sh
ls: *.jpg: No such file or directory
no

$ cat jpg2.sh
#!/bin/bash
if [ $(ls *.jpg | wc -l) = 0 ]; then
    echo "yes"
else
    echo "no"
fi

$ ./jpg2.sh
ls: *.jpg: No such file or directory
yes
```

**Follow-up**

I testify that the ticked answer is to the point -- `wc -l` has some extra white spaces in its return value. After adding `set -x` to both scripts, the difference surfaces for itself.

```sh
$ ./jpg1.sh
++ wc -l
++ ls '*.jpg'
ls: *.jpg: No such file or directory
+ '[' '       0' = 0 ']'
+ echo no
no

$ ./jpg2.sh
++ wc -l
++ ls '*.jpg'
ls: *.jpg: No such file or directory
+ '[' 0 = 0 ']'
+ echo yes
yes
```

By the way my system is macOS Catalina.

Comment: ...that said, `ls | wc` isn't good practice regardless. See [BashFAQ #4: *How can I check whether a directory is empty or not? How do I check for any *.mpg files, or count how many there are?*](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/004) for more reliable alternatives. Also relevant is [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: ...there's some relevant discussion in [`wc` on OS X return includes spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30927590/wc-on-osx-return-includes-spaces)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On some systems this is false because `wc -l` pads its answer with whitespace, and the string you're comparing against -- `0` -- doesn't contain any whitespace at all. When you use quotes, the exact output is compared; when you leave them off, the output is split into individual words based on whitespace, and each of those words is expanded as a glob, before it's put on the `[` command line. To determine whether you're on such a system, add `set -x` to your script to enable trace-level logging so you can see the exact values `[` is being asked to compare.

In present circumstances, the entire problem is trivially avoided: There's no reason to use *either* `ls` or `wc` for this purpose.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s nullglob
jpegs=( *.jpg )
if (( ${#jpegs[@]} == 0 )); then
  echo "No JPEG files were found"
else
  echo "Exactly ${#jpegs[@]} JPEG files were found"
fi
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing nice answer sir. You mentioned `On some systems this is false because wc -l pads its answer with whitespace` when I do `wc -l < Input_file` it prints number of lines with no spaces in starting(may be Linux comes in criteria of not printing spaces before). So is statement true for both command styles(`wc -l Input_file` OR `wc -l < Input_file`) or its nothing related to way of passing Input_file, thank you.

Comment: …that said, square braces are for string comparisons. Since the output of `wc` is expected to be numeric, one might also consider an arithmetic expression such as `if (( $(ls *.jpg | wc -l) == 0 ))`. One would be wrong, but arguably _less wrong_. But this answer is even less wrong.

Comment: @kojiro even sticking with the original `[`...`]`, you could use `-eq` to do a numeric instead of string comparison. But as Charles noted in his comment on the question, the entire approach of using `ls | wc` is fundamentally flawed. Too many variables make it unreliable, and when you're using a shell glob `ls` is basically turned into just an expensive `echo` anyway.

Comment: It doesn't matter for a short standalone script like this, but FWIW, since `nullglob` is a global option, you may want to set it temporarily and then restore its previous setting, which you could so with something like `reset=$(shopt -p nullglob); shopt -s nullglob` and then `$reset` at the end.

Comment: _nod_. I might `eval "$reset"` there so we continue to work if a future version of `shopt -p` includes quotes in its output, but it's a good suggestion.

Comment: @MarkReed, ...the other thing about a bare `$reset` is that it depends on IFS being at its default value to work correctly.